# Несколько анимация для одного объекта в Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

Суть проблемы - мне надо сделать несколько анимаций в Blender, чтоб потом добавить их в threejs и запускать по отдельности по триггеру. НО, я не могу никак разделить таймлайн в Blender и получается, что на один объект только одна анимация?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте Dope sheet в режиме action editor.

С помощью виджета анимационных блоков можно выбирать анимацию и редактировать ее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждую анимацию нужно пометить иконкой со щитом, иначе в противном случае не назначенные анимации будут удалены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]